# Birational smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected schemes that are smooth and projective of relative dimension 1 over $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$ for some positive integer $n$. If the function fields of $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, are $X$ and $Y$ isomorphic themselves?

If $n=1$, the answer should be positive because there is only one curve with everywhere good reduction — the projective line.

The answer is positive when the generic fibers have positive genus as I learnt from [Alex Youcis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3345291/700841).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the class groups of quaternion algebras cause trouble here.

Fix a quaternion algebra which is split away from $\infty$ and primes dividing $n$, and take a maximal order. For any finite-index right ideal of this order, which is rank $4$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module, you can form, inside the Grassmanian of rank $2$ sublattices, the closed subset consisting of those that are right ideals.

Over any place where the quaternion algebra splits, the order will be isomorphic to a matrix algebra, and the ideal will be isomorphic as a module to the algebra itself, so this will locally be $\mathbb P^1$, i.e. a smooth curve. Over $\mathbb Q$ it has a canonical isomorphism to the Brauer-Severi variety, as the ideal is isomorphic to the whole algebra over $\mathbb Q$. So if your statement is true then there must exist an isomorphism of this scheme to the Brauer-Severi scheme.

But if that happens then this isomorphism must arise from a birational automorphism of the Brauer-Severi variety composed with the canonical isomorphism, which would be an invertible element of the quaternion algebra. So it seems your statement fails unless every right ideal is generated by some element of the quaternion algebra, which is the same as saying the ideal class group is zero.

For instance if $n=p$ is a prime, for the statement to fail it suffices to find two different supersingular elliptic curves in characteristic $p$, as you will be able to for $p=11$ and all $p$ greater than $13$.

Comment: does the statement hold for e.g. $n=3$?

Comment: Hey Will. If you look at the post the OP linked to, I gave an idea of why it might be true for genus $0$. Do you know where the mistake is?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think the issue is that two different Azumaya algebras can represent the same class in the Brauer group, even if vector bundles on the base scheme are all trivial, because tensoring them both with a matrix algebra might produce the same algebra.

Comment: @WillSawin Maybe I'm being silly here, but isn't the Brauer group classifying Brauer-Severi schemes up to *isomorphism*, not up to equivalence, right? So if you know that $X$ and $Y$ are Brauer-Severi schemes over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}])$ as I tried (perhaps incorreclty) to argue in my post, then doesn't the injectivity of the localization map for Brauer groups on regular local schemes imply that generically isomorphic Brauer-Severi schemes are isomorphic? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis That is certainly not right over a general base (not a field). For instance the projectivization of any vector bundle is equivalent in the Brauer-group, but these are not necessarily isomorphic.

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry, let me be more precise. Let $S$ be a sufficiently nice scheme that I don't have to worry about the distinction between the cohomological and Azumaya Brauer group (e.g. $S$ is affine and regular more than suffices, I believe)[this is not really a necessary assumption, it's just for my psychological well-being]. We have a bijection between the isomorphism classes of Brauer-Severi schemes on $S$ of dimension $n$ and the set $H^1(S,\mathrm{PGL}_n)$ (where this etale [or flat] cohomology).

Comment: We have a natural map exact sequence $H^1(S,\mathrm{GL}_n)\to H^1(S,\mathrm{PGL}_n)\to \mathrm{Br}(S)$ and so if $S$ has no non-trivial vector bundles then an injection $H^1(S,\mathrm{PGL}_n)\to \mathrm{Br}(S)$. Since $\mathrm{Br}(S)\to\mathrm{Br}(k(S))$ is injective (again with my affineness and regularity assumptions), does it now follow that the same is true for Brauer-Severi schemes? So, why can't we apply this when $S$ is the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{n}]$ to obtain the result. Sorry if I'm being dumb.

Comment: @WillSawin Let me clarify that you should assume that the Brauer-Severi schemes have the same dimension--perhaps this is the key? Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think in the case of non-abelian groups, that exact sequence is not as powerful as you want. It implies that $H^1(S, GL_n)$ surjects onto the inverse image of $0$, but maybe not that it surjects onto another inverse image.

Comment: @WillSawin Sure, there's always the issue that the kernel being trivial is not the same as the map being injective, but essentially it suffices to check that the cohomology on $S$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ by twists of cocycles in $\mathrm{PGL}_n$  has trivial cohomology. This means checking that inner forms of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ have trivial cohomology over $S$ as well. Over a field I know that taking inner forms does not change the cohomology, so the claim (that I guess I didn't realize) is that this property fails integrally? Or, maybe to the point, that you can't phrase it in terms of group coh?

Comment: And, I suppose if you can't obviously phrase it in terms of group cohomology it's not even obvious what the above really means? I guess I was taking for granted (my bad) that the theory of 'twisting by cocycles' is something that one can make sense of over an arbitrary base, but I see that a priori that's no the case. Is that the point? Regardless, it seems as though the result is true if $X_\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis  Yes, I think inner forms can have different cohomology integrally, but it's fine if the generic fiber is $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @vrz It should hold for $n=3$ because the only quaternion algebra ramified at $3$ and $\infty$ has trivial class group.

Comment: are these quaternion algebras you are talking about provably the only obstruction? Do all smooth proper curves whose generic fiber is geometrically connected of genus 0 come from quaternion algebras?

Comment: @vrz Yes, all smooth proper curves over a field that are geometrically connected of genus zero come from quaternion algebras. Then for each such curve, there is an integral model for each maximal order - essentially because the automorphism group of both types of objects is $PGL_2$.